# Distribution of water in 3 containers

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

Given are three containers with different capacities (in liter):

A: 11

B: 8

C: 5

The question is how many possibilites are there to distribute 13 liters on to them?
I tried brute force by listing them all systematicly and have come to a result of 51 possibilities.

Is there another way without brute force? And also is my solution correct?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What do you mean with "brute force" here? Try all possibly fillings of the three containers and see which of them add up to 13?

Comment: Yes that's what I tried.

Comment: The problem is so small that it does not pay off to think of a smarter solution. Just use two nested loops and try all respective possibilities.

Comment: If you are designing algorithms then you may post your question at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ . SO may be used if you have questions about implementing existing algorithms.

Comment: The 63 don't seem to be correct, I get only 51.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming,

1. a single container can be used only once.
2. a container can only be filled fully.

The idea is to backtrack

The capacity of containers stored in `list`.

Since no language tag is specified I'll give mine in C++. The total number of combinations is present in `answer` variable and the `containers` used is stores as a list of list in `result` variable.

```
int answer = 0;
vector<vector<int>> result;
void fillJug(vector<int> list, int index, int cap, vector<int> temp) 
{
    if(cap == 0)
    {
        ++answer;
        result.push_back(temp);
        return;
    }
    if(cap < list[index])
    {
        return;
    }
    for(int i= index; i < list.size(); ++i)
    {
        vector<int> newtemp(temp);
        newtemp.push_back(list[i]);
        fillJug(list,i + 1,cap - list[i], newtemp);
    }
}
```

for container `[5, 8, 11]` and total capacity  = 13. The output will be 1. 
i.e) using `[5, 8]`

If a container can be used multiple time then change

```
fillJug(list,i + 1,cap - list[i], newtemp);
```

to

```
fillJug(list,i,cap - list[i], newtemp);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

- if you have only one container, all the water has to go into that container
- if you have more than one container, put any amount that fits into the first container and combine with the solutions for the remaining water and containers

You can implement this as a simple recursive algorithm (here in Python):

```
def divide(liters, containers):
    if len(containers) == 1 and containers[0] >= liters:
        yield [liters]
    elif len(containers) >= 2 and liters <= sum(containers):
        first, *rest = containers
        for x in range(0, min(liters, first) + 1):
            for remaining in divide(liters - x, rest):
                yield [x] + remaining

result = list(divide(13, [11, 8, 5]))
print(len(result))
```

This algorithm can also be used for more than three containers. This could be made more efficient, though. You could use some form of memoization or dynamic programming to reduce duplicate calculations, but for three containers that does not matter much.

(Of course, this assumes that the water can only be divided into multiples of one liter.)